# Function argument is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi guys i have little problem with my code. Exacly, i wrote function to count divHeight + margin. It looks like this

```
function mathMargin(divClass) {
    divClass = "'."+divClass+"'";
    divHeight = $(divClass).outerHeight(true);
    margin = divHeight * 0.3;
    result = divHeight + margin;
    return result;
}
```

I tried call function like this

```
alert(mathMargin(flatbox-title));
```

But doesn't work, console returns "flatbox" is not defined. What's wrong?

Comment: You don't need inner quotes in `"'."+divClass+"'"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass the parameter as a `string`.

```
alert(mathMargin('flatbox-title'));
```

As you write the **interpreter** sees the **parameter** as the result of math **subtraction**. (flatbox - title).

Also, you do not need `inner quotes` from function's first line. Use this instead:

```
divClass = '.' + divClass;
```

Comment: Thanks dude, you were first - it works i accept your question after 10 minutes

Answer (score 1):

`flatbox-title` is not a variable, its a string. You need to wrap it in quotes.

```
alert(mathMargin('flatbox-title'));
```

Answer (score 1):

As alternative to Alexandru-lonut Mihai and Manav answers, you could also pass the element:

```
function mathMargin(div) {
    divHeight = div.outerHeight(true);
    margin = divHeight * 0.3;
    result = divHeight + margin;
    return result;
}

alert(mathMargin( $('.flatbox-title) ));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Mistakes**

- divClass = "'."+divClass+"'";       this will create single quoted
  string.  check yourself in console.
- while calling function put double quote for the parameter you are
  sending

```js
function mathMargin(divClass) {
    divClass = "."+divClass;
    divHeight = $(divClass).outerHeight(true);
    margin = divHeight * 0.3;
    result = divHeight + margin;
    return result;
}
alert(mathMargin('flatbox-title'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="flatbox-title">fa
faww
fwafaw
fawfa
w</div>
```

Comment: @sauero .. check snippet

Answer (score 0):

Interpreter treats `flatbox-title` as variable, not as a string (`'flatbox-title'`) and since you have no such variable declared it throws an exception.

On the other side, why overcomplicate simple code? Consider it rewriting it as:

```
function mathMargin(divClass) {
    var divHeight = $("."+divClass).outerHeight(true);
    return divHeight * 1.3;
}
```

Please note, that you forget `var` keyword before your variables. Not sure if it was on purpose or not, but generally you should avoid doing this, as  without it a global variables will be created. This can cause some nasty bugs later on...